# After a crash app starts previous activity

Tags: android

Say I have 3 activities A and B and c. App starts with A I open B than I open C. Than there is a crash in C. Instead of just closing the app entirely android opens activity B, which is bad for me because B  doesn't work well than (maybe code is not very good). Anyway I'd like the crash to kill the app not just start the previous activity. Is that possible? BTW, this app is quite big and handling each activity separately isn't the best solution for me.

Comment: Why not just fix the crash in the first place? If you really want you can just call finish() on each activity when you start a new one.

Comment: @dymmeh I need a workaround fast. I'll fix crashes when I have more time. Calling finish won't work. I want it only when a crash occurs.

Comment: A logcat around the time of the crash may be helpful here.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can easily do it.

**Activity A:**
After calling B use a finish keyword:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,B_Activity.class);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

Similarly in **Activity B:**

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,C_Activity.class);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

Now put the code that is crashing of **Activity C** in **try catch block**

```
try
{
}
catch(Exception e)
{
     finish();
}
```

What this does this if any problem in **Activity C** it will be catched and the **Activity C** will be finished , which then will go to the calling activity i.e **B** which will also finish and similarly **Activity A** also finishes. 
And Hence when the app re-starts it will start from Activity A.

Comment: Calling finish won't work. I want it only when a crash occurs.

Comment: "Now put the entire code of Activity C in try catch block"  *cringe*

Comment: yes the code reaches the Catch only when there is a error/crash and then the finish will be called..